# Writing multi-dimensional list value to a file in Python

Tags: python, list

Thanks for clearing up my confusions on my previous question of saving data from file to multidimensional list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018994/copying-file-content-to-multi-dimensional-list-in-python)

I look up through the Internet to do the reverse, saving multidimensional list to a file. But, I didn't get any lead to compute that. If its not too much, I would appreciate if you can suggest me how could I save a multidimensional list to a file.

The list is something like

```
['b',30.83,0,'u','g','w','v',1.25,'t','t',01,'f','g',00202,0,+]
['a',58.67,4.46,'u','g','q','h',3.04,'t','t',06,'f','g',00043,560,+]
```

The format needed to be saved in the file is

```
b,30.83,0,u,g,w,v,1.25,t,t,01,f,g,00202,0,+
a,58.67,4.46,u,g,q,h,3.04,t,t,06,f,g,00043,560,+
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Numbers like `00043` are automatically converted to integers, you should convert them to strings if you want to store them as is.

Comment: Most notably, ``00043 == 35`` in python2 and ``SyntaxError`` in python3. A leading zero indicates a octal number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
   writer.writerows(my_list)  #considering my_list is a list of lists.
```

Answer (score 1):

Join each list with "," & write as a line to your file.